# Can't access property on API from petfinder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, petfinder

I'm trying to pull data from the Petfinder API.  I get a good response and can see the properties available but as soon as I try and access the pets property I get an error.  I'm grabbing the promise fine but clearly messing up somewhere else.  Hoping someone can help me figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the code and what the promise returns

```
console.log(this.props.pets.petfinder)
```

[image: Then as soon as I add .pets to the r]

Here is the code that causes the error

```
console.log(this.props.pets.petfinder.pets)
```

[image]

Here is the action that is calling the api

```
export const getPets = () => {
    const myInits = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors'
  }
  const promise = axios.get('http://api.petfinder.com/pet.find?key=mykey&format=json&location=85282', myInits)
  return {
      type: GET_PETS,
      payload: promise
  }
}
```

Comment: Insert some code example or complete response object. Anyway see the object structure at http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow what you are asking for??  The first image is the response from the API and I see the "pets" node/property and as soon as I try and access it I get the second image which is an error.